# maven scm plugin migration from SVN to GIT

Tags: java, git, maven, svn

I had a maven project structure including  following projects

- server
- client
- node

This is my module structure in main pom

```
    <modules>
    <module>server</module>
    <module>node</module>
    <module>help</module>
    <module>client</module>

</modules>
```

I defined an automatic jar creation mechanism that runs on server machine. It checkouts code for each module, compiles, builds, etc. In each module, I defined maven scm blug in for checking out latest code for related module (Server, client , node).

For example, this is pom.xml for server side.

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://ip/svn/repositoryName/trunk/projectName/server/src</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://ip/svn/repositoryName/trunk/projectName/server/src</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

And this is profile for refreshing

```
    <profile>
        <id>environment-refresh-sources</id>

        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>refreshSources</name>
                <value>true</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <username>maven.user</username>
                        <password>password</password>
                        <checkoutDirectory>${basedir}/src</checkoutDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>CheckoutFromSVN</id>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>checkout</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

We have this configuration for each module. Just scm connection is changing. For example: this is for client.

```
<connection>scm:svn:https://ip/svn/repositoryName/trunk/projectName/client/src</connection>
```

Now I am trying to migrate from SVN to GIT. But I am not able to configure maven plug in to work in this way.

This is my scm configuration for GIT.

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:http://maven.user@ip/scm/sig/project.git</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:http://maven.user@ip/scm/sig/project.git</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

This is my new plugin for git. I have added branch part. Now it checkouts master branch including server, client etc. modules. How can I work in same way with GIT.

```
<artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.8.1</version>
<configuration>
   <connectionType>developerConnection</connectionType>
   <scmVersion>master</scmVersion>
   <scmVersionType>branch</scmVersionType>
   <username>maven.user</username>
   <password>password</password>    
   <checkoutDirectory>${basedir}/src</checkoutDirectory>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
       <id>CheckoutFromGIT</id>
       <phase>initialize</phase>
       <goals>
          <goal>checkout</goal>
       </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```